# UIView copy issue in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiview, ios9, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Using below technique I am copying a view, everything was fine but in iOS 9 it fails to copy the used images in the cloneView.

```
let cloneView =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(
    NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(view1))
```

Can anyone help me to resolved this. Any advise will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `view1` is an `UIImageView` and you are assigning the image to it from `imageNamed:` API, like so

```
view1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
```

It's bit strange that you got it working for iOS8 as this doesn't work for me.

Though i don't know the internal implementation of archive/unarchive methods, but i took a guess that it is not allowing to create a copy of view's image.
You can solve this by loading the content of `UIImage` to your source view.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"png"];
view1.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now you can copy the view and will get the image in your clone view as well.

Comment: `view1` is an instance `UIView` which contain multiple controls like UITextField, UIButton, UIImageView etc and I am setting the image from interface builder.

Comment: @TapasPal - Ok, Can you try then setting the image like i suggested above. Remove it from IB for now and see if that works.

Comment: @TapasPal - Did you find the solution for your problem? I was wondering if my idea was correct. Or you can post the solution of your own if there was something else to it.

Comment: Till now I am looking for it solution.